# Не совсем правильно работает задача в gulp

Tags: gulp

Нужно: livereload и sass.
Код:

```js
var 
gulp = require('gulp'),
sass = require('gulp-sass'),
livereload = require('gulp-livereload');


gulp.task('sass', function(){
    gulp.src('./opencart.loc/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./opencart.loc'))
    .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function(){
    livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch('./opencart.loc/**/*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
});
```

В результате задача отрабатывает ровно один раз при сохранении файла sass. В этот момент в консоли появляется:

```
 C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart.loc\style.css reloaded.
```

И всё, на последующие правки не реагирует. Где ошибка?
livereload версия 4

Comment: `gulp.watch('./opencart.loc', gulp.series('sass'));` попробуйте

Comment: Без изменений. Работает до первого сохранения.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.

```js
var 
gulp = require('gulp'),
sass = require('gulp-sass'),
livereload = require('gulp-livereload');




function style(){
    return gulp.src('./opencart.loc/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./opencart.loc'))
    .pipe(livereload());
}

function watch(){
    livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch('./opencart.loc/**/*.scss', style)
}


gulp.task(style, style);
gulp.task(watch, watch);
```